# javascript регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, нужно удалить в тексте все пустые bb коды, типа `[b][/b] [u][/u] [strike][/strike]` я думал это сделать при помощи array replace, но у меня сложился вопрос, можно ли это сделать с помощью map функции?

Comment: `\[[a-z]+\]\[\/[a-z]+\]` - вроде должно хватить, поправьте кто-нибудь. Не тестировал.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Ваш вариант отловит и такое: `[b][/u]'. Не факт, что автору это надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
str = 'abcd [i]def[u][/u][/i] [lol][/lol] ghij[strike][/strike]klmno';
let re1 = /\[(\w+)\]\[\/\1\]/g;
console.log(str.replace(re1, ''));

let re2 = /\[(u|i|b|strike)\]\[\/\1\]/g;
console.log(str.replace(re2, ''));
```

Не вполне ясно, к чему в вопросу упоминаются массивы.

Comment: Скажите, а если будет подобная строчка `abcd [i][u][/u][/i]` - это считается пустым?

Comment: По логике вещей, должно считаться, но у меня есть подозрение, что подобное javascript'овскими регулярками в принципе не отловить, пусть специалисты меня поправят, если я не прав.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться рекурсией или циклом, менять строчку до тех пор, пока она будет меняться. В таком случае `abcd [i][u][/u][/i] === abcd`

Comment: спасибо, а как можно изменить регулярку, чтобы работало только на опр бб кодах? типа [u][/u], [b][/b] и тд. Ибо если человек просто введет [lol][/lol] то получается выражение сработает, а это не совсем кстати, в моем случае

Comment: @Владимир Дополнил ответ.